# A small cancellation group does not contain $\mathbb{Z}^3$

Tags: group-theory, geometric-group-theory

I read somewhere that a small cancellation group (ie. a group admitting a presentation statisfying the small cancellation condition $C'(1/6)$) does not contain $\mathbb{Z}^3$, but without a precise reference. Do you know a reference containing a proof of the above statement?

Similarly, in hyperbolic groups, $\mathbb{Z}^2$ is a forbidden subgroup: it may be seen as a consequence of a more general result on centralizers. Does there exist a similar property on centralizers in small cancellation groups?

Comment: **Finitely presented** small cancellation groups are hyperbolic, but what about the general case?

Comment: This reduces to the finitely presented case. Indeed if $\Gamma$ has presentation $\langle S\mid r_n:n\ge 0\rangle$  with $S$ finite and $\Gamma$ contains a copy of $\Lambda=\mathbf{Z}^2$, then $\Gamma_n=\langle S\mid r_n:0\le k\le n\rangle$ contains a copy of $\Lambda$ for $n$ large enough. (More generally this holds for an arbitrary finitely presented group $\Lambda$.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case you are still interested: It suffices to work with presentations $P$ satisfying the small cancellation condition $C(6)$. Given such a presentation $P$ of a group $G$, one builds a 2-dimensional CAT(0) complex $X_P$ on which the group $G$ acts with finite point-stabilizers. (This, I think, is explained in Bridson and Haefliger's book.) In particular, $X_P$ is aspherical. If no relator in $P$ is a proper power, then the complex $X_P$ is the universal cover of the presentation complex of $P$ and asphericity of this complex was known as early as in 1981 (Chiswell-Collins-Huebschmann).

Since $X_P$ is 2-dimensional and aspherical, the rational cohomological dimension of $G$ is at most 2. But $Z^3$ has rational cohomological dimension 3. Therefore, $G$ cannot contain a copy of $Z^3$.

The same argument applies to presentations satisfying other small cancellation conditions such as C(4)-T(4), etc.

Comment: I took a look in Bridson and Haefliger's book, but small cancellation groups do not seem to be studied there. If you have a reference, I am interested.